# Toggle native iOS datepicker for date input

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating web app optimized for iOS devices. Now I use `<input type="date"/>`. I want to make it invisible and instead use my own `div` with a date styled and formatted inside it. Though I need to open native DatePicker as if I clicked the date input.

Is it possible to launch it with something like `input_date.click()` or similar?

Comment: not `click` but `focus`, so yes you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, quite easily. See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KGph8/3/).

```
$('#datefield').click(function(){
    $('#datepicker').focus();
});

.hide {
   position: absolute !important;
   top: -9999px !important;
   left: -9999px !important;
}

<input id="datepicker" type="date" class="hide"/>
<div id="datefield">Heeeey</div>
```

Just make sure you don't hide the input-field using `display:none`, as this will disable interaction, even through `$.focus()`.

Comment: This is not working. I am unable to open the native picker by clicking on another field. Have you tested this ?